# PHPMYADMIN You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2, phpmyadmin

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin`:

```
<VirtualHost *:133>
               ServerName phpmyadmin
               DocumentRoot /var/www-133
               </VirtualHost>
```

`/etc/apache2/ports.conf`:

```
Listen 80
Listen 133

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

How would I stop apache port 133 from listening to 443 cause I am not connecting via https, only http.

Comment: Why do you listen to port 133?

Comment: I want my phpmyadmin on a different port @MichaelHampton

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions. Using an arbitrary port doesn't increase security, whereas using TLS to encrypt the connection would. I know how to use a gun, but won't teach you shooting your leg.